# Change UI typehead value based on user select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using this directive https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

Normal typehead works fine but how to change the source based on user select ? In jQuery we can change but how to do it in ui AngularJS typehead

my plunker [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/rfClV33x1IWgyQcMkPFr/)

Comment: Can you show the code you are working with?

Comment: Show code or add plunker.

Comment: my plunker  

[link](https://embed.plnkr.co/rfClV33x1IWgyQcMkPFr/)

Comment: for name of sake i put two http typehead ., the typehead should be oly one  when the user selects from the drop down the source of typehead have to change